# Using .after but only if the value does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running this code to insert a HTML line after the id `#wp_menu`:

```
$(document).on('closing', '.remodal', function (e) {
    $('.menu_name').each(function() {
        $('#wp_menu').after('<div class="tag">' + $(this).val() + '</div>');
    });
});
```

The problem is, every time I run this loop, I'll get duplicated values and this is not what I want. How can I check if the code was inserted before?

This is a simple example that may explain my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/vLqonqpk/

So when you click on "add" multiple times, it will add the same values over and over again.

Comment: @j08691 thank you, this is very good to know but it is not exactly what I am looking for. This will make the loop run only once. But I need to run it multiple times, since every time I run it, there could be new values in it. But what I don't want is to insert the old values which have been inserted before.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a [mcve] of what you're working with?

Comment: @j08691 I have added an example.

Comment: Should every entry be unique? E.g. if two words are duplicated but third word not -> should third word/value be placed in tag div?

Comment: @sinisake yes, each word should be unique. If two words are duplicated but the third word is not, so the third word should be placed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
arr = [];


$('button').click(function() {

    $('ul input').each(function() {
        if ($.inArray($(this).val(), arr) == -1) {
            $('#wp_menu').after('<div class="tag">' + $(this).val() + '</div>');

            arr.push($(this).val());
        }



    });
    console.log(arr);
});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/vLqonqpk/1/

So, create array of values, check if current val(s) from inputs are duplicated, and place just unique values. Of course, you can add additional checks for empty string, and give user some alerts/warnings (create else block for that purpose), if needed, etc, etc...

But this is basic idea which should work.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Simply isolate the jQuery selector and check its existence.</strike>

```
$(document).on('closing', '.remodal', function (e) {
    $('.menu_name').each(function() {
        var $wp_menu = $('#wp_menu');
        var $tag = $wp_menu.next('.tag'); // .siblings() also works

        // Now you check if it exists, and create it if not
        if (!$tag.length)
            $tag = $('<div class="tag">').insertAfter($wp_menu);

        // Simply update the content, element will always exist
        $tag.text($(this).val()); // .html() also works
    });
});
```

I'm sure there's several ways to do it, this is just one of them.

I now realize your problem is not duplicating tags, but values. Basically you want a HashSet. Please accept [sinisake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41190677/5529144) instead

Comment: For some reason this will only add and update only one value. I am not able to add multiple values.

Comment: That would be because `$('#wp_menu')` is always the same element. Maybe you need to change this selector...

Comment: I now realize your problem is not duplicating tags, but values. Basically you want a HashSet. Please accept sinisake's answer instead